# How do I use htaccess to collect jsonp callback value

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a url

api/something/json?callback=abc and I want to redirect it to

dothis.php?strEndPoint=something&callback=abc&format=json

The base htaccess I tried was:

RewriteRule ^api/(.*)/(json)?callback=(.*) client.php?strEndPoint=$1&callback=$3&format=($2)

Doesn't appear to work : p

Answer (score 0):

tested

using .*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} callback\=(.*)
RewriteRule /api/(.*)/(json) /client.php?strEndPoint=$1&callback=%1&format=$2 [R=301]
```

you can remove r=301 just for test

```
$ curl localhost/api/1111/json?callback=2222 -I
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Date: Fri, 01 Nov 2013 03:16:25 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.24 (Unix) DAV/2 mod_ssl/2.2.24 OpenSSL/0.9.8y
Location: http://localhost/client.php?strEndPoint=1111&callback=2222&format=json
```